# A "known" Pythagorean identity in algebra?

Tags: symmetric-functions, polynomials

Some will recognize this as similar to a question I asked before, but
I want to ask it without the trigonometry.

Let $e_k$ be the $k$th-degree elementary symmetric polynomial in
$x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$.  If $k$ is more than the number of $x$s, then
$e_k$ is the sum of no terms and is $0$.  From one POV, the following
Pythagorean identities are as elementary as anything not in the
high-school curriculum:
$$
(e_0+e_2+e_4+\cdots)^2 - (e_1+e_3+e_5+\cdots)^2 =
(1-x_1^2)(1-x_2^2)(1-x_3^2)\cdots
$$
$$
(e_0-e_2+e_4-\cdots)^2 + (e_1-e_3+e_5-\cdots)^2 =
(1+x_1^2)(1+x_2^2)(1+x_3^2)\cdots
$$
So are these "known" in the sense of being in refereed publications
one could cite?  And if not, are they "known" in the sense that some
people see them mentioned or explicitly used from time to time?

(And if there should happen to be infinitely many $x$s, could this
still be considered only algebra by thinking of these as a sort of
"formal" series?)

Comment: What's the complete homogeneous symmetric function analogue?  I might recognize that more easily.  I get the feeling this is standard or at least a routine application of something standard in symmetric function theory.  The right hand sides look like the squares of Cauchy kernels.


Answer (score 10):

These are both simple corollaries of
$$\sum_{k\geq 0} t^ke_k(x_1,x_2,\dots)=\prod_{k\geq 0}(1+tx_k).$$

There is a typo in both your identities. They should read,
$$(e_0+e_2+\cdots)^2-(e_1+e_3+\cdots)^2=(e_0+e_1+e_2+\cdots)(e_0-e_1+e_2-\cdots)$$
$$=\prod_{k\geq 0}(1+x_k)\prod_{k\geq 0}(1-x_k)=(1-x_1^2)(1-x_2^2)\cdots,$$
and
$$(e_0-e_2+e_4-\cdots)^2+(e_1-e_3+e_5-\cdots)^2=(\mathfrak {Re}[\prod_{k\geq 0}(1+ix_k)])^2+(\mathfrak{Im}[\prod_{k\geq 0}(1+ix_k)])^2$$
$$=(1+x_1^2)(1+x_2^2)\cdots$$

Comment: Can you cite a book or refereed paper that states the identity of which these are corollaries?

Comment: Look at chapter 1 in Macdonald's book on symmetric functions. Though, that identity is very close to the definition of the elementary symmetric polynomials :)

Comment: The odd thing is that when the $x$s are sines and the first identity generalizes $1-\sin^2\theta=\cos^2\theta$, or the $x$s are tangents and the second identity generalizes $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$, the validity of the identities in no way depends on the fact that the circle is parametrized by arc length rather than in some other way, but yet the way I found these identities was by deriving them from an identity one side of which was $\tan(\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3+\cdots)$.

Comment: To be more specific, this is Equation 2.2 in Section 2 of Chapter I, found on p. 19 of the 2nd edition.
